# Matillion to Snowflake connection is showing error 'Default Database must not be empty'

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connectivity, key-pair, matillion

I am trying to connect Snowflake to Matillion ETL using key-pair authentication.
I'm facing the error '***Default Database must not be empty***'.
We have given a default database from Snowflake side as well.
[click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8KD.png)
In this environment, we are unable to see the dropdown for default database. We have even tried manually passing the default variables but it shows the error 'invalid JWT token' and our key-pair is correct since we have tested it in other environment where it is working.

When we try to establish the connectivity from another environment of ours, it is successful. We can see a list of options to select from in the dropdown of default database(which is how it should ideally be). [click to see successful connection in the other environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VoO6.png)

Comment: Can you connect to the Snowflake account, using the same key-pair authentication, via SnowSQL?

Comment: How is the JWT token generated? Is it generated from another environment and being reused in this "non-working environment"?

Comment: @NickW not via SnowSQL, but using another environment, yes.

Comment: @SrinathMenon the key pair we are using is generated from a central server (which is connected to all environments so shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: If you run "show user..." in the account you can't connect to, does it show the correct values in the RSA_PUBLIC_KEY/RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_2 parameters?

Comment: If you're getting Invalid JWT token on this environment alone, check if the cause is not one of the ones listed [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Key-Based-Authentication-Failed-with-JWT-token-is-invalid-Error)

Comment: @meghnaaJaiswal - I would suggest to generate the JWT token afresh using the local server and try it again: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Use-SnowSQL-to-generate-JWT-Token-for-Key-Pair-Authentication-Mechanism

Comment: @Sergiu yes, checked that link out before, we checked for all those causes

Comment: @SrinathMenon we tried with a fresh key-pair as well, it was still not showing the default parameters in the dropdown

Comment: This is mostly a Matillion issue rather than Snowflake. Unless you can get JDBC logs I would suggest to reach out to Matillion.

Comment: If you can't connect via SnowSQL then it is a Snowflake issue. Try getting that to work, using the Snowflake logs, and when that's working have another go with Matillion

Comment: First and foremost use the new generated key-pair and try to login from SnowSQL, it that works successfully, it would isolate the issue to Matillion. Collect the snowsql logs if the new key-pair fails for further review.

Answer (score 1):

The Default Database, Warehouse and Schema are all set in the 3rd dialog in Matillion's Environment setup window.

According to [this Matillion guide to Connecting Matillion ETL to Snowflake](https://www.matillion.com/resources/blog/connecting-matillion-etl-to-snowflake-a-guide), these dropdowns can show no selectable values if there are any problems on the previous (2nd dialog).

- If it is an account level problem (account not correct, or no network access) then the default database dropdown list will show a "Loading..." message for several seconds before rendering an empty list. I guess it tries to make network contact in the background, and eventually times out. You will see this if you go backwards and forwards between the 2nd and 3rd dialogs.
- In contrast, if it is a user level problem (bad credentials, or not enough privileges) then the default database dropdown will be blank immediately when you enter the 3rd dialog.

According to [this Matillion document on environments](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2679765) you can use either a password or a private key to authenticate into Snowflake. So - as per the comments - I agree that if you can connect to Snowflake using the same Account, username and private key using a different SQL client, then it should also work in Matillion ETL.